# inject svg файла при изменении html документа

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, svg-спрайт

Есть небольшая gulp сборка для проекта.

**Плагины:**

- [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject)
- [browsersync](https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp)
- [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch)
- [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref)

**gulpfile.js:**

```
var 
    gulp         = require('gulp'),
    ...

var path = {
    app : {          // Исходники
        html   : 'app/*.html',
        js     : 'app/js/*.js',
        svg    : 'app/**/*.svg',
    },
    dist : {         // Релиз
        html   : 'dist/',
        js     : 'dist/js/',
    },
    watch : {        // Наблюдение
        html   : 'app/**/*.html',
        svg    : 'app/**/*.svg',
        js     : 'app/js/**/*.js',
    }
};

// Настройка сервера
var config = {
    server : {
        'baseDir' : './dist'
    },
    host : 'localhost',
    port : 9000,
    tunel : true,
};

// Работа с HTML
gulp.task('html', ['svg'], function(){
    gulp.src(path.app.html)
        .pipe(rigger())     
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))        
        .pipe(inject(svgContent, { transform: fileContents }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream : true}));
});

// Работа с JS
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src(path.app.js)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
        .pipe(reload({stream : true}));
});

// Работа с SVG
function fileContents (filePath, file) {
    return file.contents.toString();}

var svgContent = gulp.src(path.app.svg)
                   .pipe(svgmin())
                   .pipe(svgstore({ inlineSvg: true }))
                   .pipe(reload({stream : true}));

gulp.task('svg', function () {
    var svgs = svgContent;
});



// Наблюдение
gulp.task('watch', function () {    
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb){
        gulp.start('html');
    });
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb){
        gulp.start('svg');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb){
        gulp.start('js');
    });
});

// Запуск вебсервера
gulp.task('webserver', function(){
    browserSync(config);
});

// Чистка
gulp.task('clean', function(cb){
    clean(path.clean, cb);
});

// Задачи по-умолчанию
gulp.task('default', [
    'html',
    'svg',
    'js',
    'webserver',
    'watch' 
]);
```

**html:**

```
...
<div style="height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden">
  <!-- inject:svg --><!-- endinject -->
</div>
...

<!-- build:js js/vendor.js -->  
  <script src="libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  ...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Все  работает неплохо, до изменений в html файле. Любое изменение приводит к исчезновению скомпилированного инлайн `svg` файла внутри html файла (внутри inject).

**Вопрос:** Можно ли настроить gulpfile.js так, чтобы можно было вносить изменения в html файл без перезапуска всей сборки в консоли и без потери сформированного svg спрайта внутри html файла?

---

Пробую так:

В **gulpfile.js**:

```
// Таск для html
gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src(path.app.html) 
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))     
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream : true}));
});

// Таск для SVG
gulp.task('svg', function () {

    var svgs = gulp.src(path.app.svg)
            .pipe(svgstore({ inlineSvg: true }));

    function fileContents (filePath, file) {
        return file.contents.toString();
    }

    return gulp.src(path.app.html)
        .pipe(inject(svgs, { transform: fileContents }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.other));
});
```

Все работает, вебсервер перезапускается очищается с внесением изменений в любой файл html, css и сохранением  `svg` спрайта, **НО перестал работать `useref()`**.

```
<!-- build:js js/vendor.js -->  
    <script src="libs/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/animate/wow.min.js"></script>
    ....
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Собирает **vendor.js**, но **не записывает в `html`**. А должен после генерации быть:

```
<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, сам svg и масштабирование тут  не при чем))))

Comment: Так что за решение-то?

Answer (score 2):

Как альтернатива, но не решение. Пришлось отказаться от inject `svg` и заменить его на rigger.

В **html**:

```
//= svg-sprite.html
```

Соответственно создаю еще файл **svg-sprite.html** в который вставляю сгенерированный svg спрайт. Генерирую с помощью ресурса [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/).

**gulpfile.js**:

```
// Work with HTML
gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src(path.app.html)
        .pipe(rigger()) 
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))  
        //.pipe(inject(svgContent, { transform: fileContents }))  
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html))
        .pipe(reload({stream : true}));
});
```

Все таски по `svg` не нужны.